# List of amazing things you can do with Mathematica

Tags: programming, education

What is the coolest (amazing) thing you can do with *Mathematica*?

for instance

there are my favorite things

[Automating xkcd Diagrams](http://blog.wolfram.com/2012/10/05/automating-xkcd-diagrams-transforming-serious-to-funny/)

[Extending Van Gogh’s Starry Night with Inpainting](http://blog.wolfram.com/2014/12/01/extending-van-goghs-starry-night-with-inpainting/)

[image]

[Making Formulas… for Everything—From Pi to the Pink Panther to Sir Isaac Newton](http://blog.wolfram.com/2013/05/17/making-formulas-for-everything-from-pi-to-the-pink-panther-to-sir-isaac-newton/)

[image]

[image]

**.**

**.**

**.**

Comment: I was tempted to put on hold as "too broad", but then decided I'll let other users decide for themselves. I have set this CW as a compromise, tho.